# Synchronous copying to USB drive in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I've been copying a bunch of files between Windows 7 computers using a USB 3.0 thumb drive. I've noticed that copying multiple files together in one copy attempt is significantly faster than copying them separately.

Is there some way to have Windows queue multiple separate copies like it does with grouped copies?

Copying a set of files together averages 65MB/s, but once I try two at a time, it drops way down to 7MB/s each.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a folder sync program, like [Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) or [AllSync](http://allwaysync.com/)

Another method would be to try the good ol' built in Microsoft Briefcase.

Comment: I'm not trying to sync an entire folder. I'm trying to copy over a bunch of large files from a variety of different locations on the source drive to the root of the USB stick.